# How can I install FORTRAN95 in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, fortran

I met problem in installing FORTRAN95 in ubuntu 10.04? Which link I have to use for downloading FORTRANN95 and please mention the way to install. I read the manual but I didn't understood. Please clearly mention the steps to download and to install FORTRAN95 in ubuntu 10.04

Comment: "apt-get install gfortran" : http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gfortran

Answer (score 1):

go to synaptic package manager (system/admistration) and type gfortran and click on it and install (it is the graphical way of doing apt-get install  gfortran) this would be easier